# Select users who answered all the questions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables like these:

Table **ANSWER**

```
idAnswer   idQuestion   Status   idGame
----------------------------------------
1          9            1        1
2          6            NULL     1
3          6            1        2
4          3            NULL     2
5          1            1        3
6          6            1        3
7          9            1        4
8          6            1        4
```

Table **GAME**:

```
idGame   idUser
----------------
1        Greg
2        Greg
3        Jack
4        Frank
```

I want to get only those who answered the same question as the game n°4, like this:

Desired result:

```
idUser
-------
Greg
Frank
```

Status is used to check if the question has been answered. If it is NULL, the user didn't answer it.

Here, Frank had a very similar game (it's obvious, because it's the same, the n°4).

Greg didn't played a similar game, but answered in 2 others the same questions, so he appears in the result.

Jack did answered one of the question (n°6) but didn't answered the other one (n°9), so Jack doesn't appear.

So, the result includes only those who answered the same questions as another game, no matter if it's in a similar game or in multiple one.

Games are randomly generated. Sometimes, user can answer a question they already encounter or/and answered. (Like Greg, in game 1 and 2).

I tried a lot of queries. I can post them if you want.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I don't know how to keep the spacing without using the code quote, sorry about that.

Comment: Could you give us the wanted result !!?

Comment: I think that what he wants is the userid of everyone that has answered the same questions as Frank (idGame 4).

In this example the result would be just Frank as no one else has answered only question 6 and 9.

Comment: I edited the post to cover some missing informations for a better understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT g.idUser, COUNT(*) as NumberOfAnswers
FROM answer a
      INNER JOIN game g ON a.idGame = g.idGame
WHERE a.idQuestion IN (9,6)
GROUP BY g.idUser
HAVING NumberOfAnswers = 2
```

I think this solution match your requirements if the users cannot answer the same question twice in the same game and if you doesn't mind to show users who has answered more questions.

EDIT:

For a more generic solution, you could adapt the query to something like this:

```
SELECT g.idUser, COUNT(*) as NumberOfAnswers
FROM answer a
    INNER JOIN game g ON a.idGame = g.idGame
WHERE a.idCuestion IN (SELECT idQuestion FROM answer WHERE idGame=[DESIRED_GAME])
GROUP BY g.IdUser
HAVING NumberOfAnswers = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answer WHERE idGame = [DESIRED_GAME]
```

Comment: This only works for this specific example. As soon as the data is different this would no longer give the desired result.

Comment: @E.Hekkert Adapting the query to a more generic enviroment shouldn't be so hard, If the conditions I specify after the first solution are correct. However I added a generic solution too.

Comment: Yes it has to be generic, since the number of answer by games might change in the future. But I did not precised it, Thank you for the reply! I'm going to try that now!

Comment: Ok, I didn't precise on my post, so it's my bad. I don't get anything from the second querry because the user answered the questions multiple times. so the count can't be equal to 2. Moreover, you didn't used the Status. But this is not a big issue since I can add it without troubles. I edit my post right away to precise all the things I missed to mention.

Comment: @NekiCoule I see the problem. If the user has played multiple times, he could be ansewered the same question twice, so if game nº4 has answered question (9,6) a user who whas played two times answering questions (9,1) and (9,7), will match my query but not your requeriments. If you want to limit the solution to a game, just add `g.IdGame` in both `SELECT` and `Group by`. If you need  to take care about multiple games, leave a comment. Maybe i could think a work around.

Comment: It was as simple as adding the question id in the select and group by! Thank you so much!